# How to change the VisualStudio's run shortcut run command (python)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

So i recently had a problem that regarded the command that is executed in vsc's integrated terminal every time [the little triangular button on top right corner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7B5z.png) is pressed

It executes a command that consists of file path to `python.exe` file, and the currently selected file:

```
[path to current folder]>C:/Users/[username]/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/python.exe [currently selected file]
```

and i had problems with that, it didn't recognize some modules. So i found out if i do it by running the command `python [currently selected file]` it works flawlessly.

I found a setting in the python extension that is labeled `python.pythonPath`, which i edited from original to `"python.pythonPath": "python"`, which i thought would work but it didn't. I have been digging trough the extention settings for some time now, and i have not been able to find this setting.

Is it even possible? Do i do it right? Is it even done by the python extention?

Answer (score 0):

If you use cmd, it can run the Python files properly,it is recommended that you check whether the environment variables are correct. Reference:[This](https://docs.python.org/2/using/windows.html#excursus-setting-environment-variables).

To better run Python files in vscode, you could set up the vcode [virtual environment](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_environment-variable-definitions-file).

As for the path '`python.pythonPath`', you could refer to:[pythonpath](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_manually-specify-an-interpreter).